# In Elasticsearch, can an update request respond with a "DELETED" status?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-rest-client

I was reviewing the Elasticsearch official documentation to understand the possible responses of an update request (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-update.html#java-rest-high-document-update-response). According to the documentation, an update request can respond with a "DELETED" status. However, from my understanding, I thought that update requests should only have statuses such as "CREATED", "UPDATED", and "NOOP".

Can someone please clarify under what circumstances an update request in Elasticsearch might respond with a "DELETED" status? Is this a common scenario, or is it an edge case that occurs under specific conditions?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Update request response

Answer (score 0):

A "DELETED" status in Elasticsearch update requests can happen when the document that is being updated has been deleted from the index before the update request is processed. This can happen due to lifecycle management policies, concurrent operations, replication delays or TTL expiration, in a distributed environment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding 

But as you mentioned if the document is deleted before the update request, when the update request executes it should get a response as NOOP isn't it? 

why does the update request respond with a DELETED status in that case as well?

back to the same question again.